# Reading a massive text file and storing the data - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that reads a file and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

```
function WordCount(){}

WordCount.prototype.readfile = function(file) {
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data)) {
    if (err) throw err;
  }
}
module.exports = WordCount;
```

Test:

```
describe('wordCount',function(){

  var wordCount;

  beforeEach(function(){
    wordcount = new WordCount
  });

describe("When trying to read a file", function() {
  it('will not throw an error when reading the file', function() {
    expect(wordCount.readFile(reader)).not.toThrow(err);
  });
  it('will throw an error if a file is missing', function() {
    expect(wordCount.readFile()).toThrow(err);
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: You have a syntax error: `fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data){ your function here instead}) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in this string: `fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data)) {`, callback of readfile is wrong.

You need `fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data){...});`
I recommend use ide with jshinter or jslinter. This is a common situation, and you need to watch brackets and ";". jslint and jshint are help with it bugs.